# Javascript: Creating a Table from an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I have an HTML Table:

`<table>
        <tr id="0"></tr>
        <tr id="1"></tr>
        <tr id="2"></tr>
        <tr id="3"></tr>
    </table>`

I then make an array of 16 numbers, shuffle the array, and then add one cell per number in Javascript.

```
var numbers = shuffle([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8]);
console.log(numbers)

function shuffle(o) {
            for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
            return o;
}
function addCell(row, number) {
            var cell = document.getElementById(row).insertCell(0)
            cell.innerHTML = number;
}
function setNumbers() {
    var column = 0;
    var row = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= numbers.length; i++) {
        column = column + 1;
        if (column > 4) {
            column = 0;
            row = row + 1;
        }
        console.log(row)
        addCell(row, numbers[i]);
    }
}
setNumbers()
```

The function `setNumbers()` should create a table with 4 rows and 4 columns. 
It should create something like this:

```
5 7 6 2
1 4 3 4
8 3 2 1
5 6 7 8
```

However, it creates this:

```
8   5   1   5
6   2   4   6   4
7   2   8   3   1
undefined   3   7
```

Four numbers in row 1,

Five numbers in rows 2 and 3,

and 2 numbers and an undefined in row 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a minor bug in the handling of the value of `column`, since you are checking `column > 4` from the second loop onward the row will have 5 items

```js
var numbers = shuffle([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8]);
console.log(numbers.length, numbers)

function shuffle(o) {
  for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
  return o;
}

function addCell(row, number) {
  var cell = document.getElementById(row).insertCell(0)
  cell.innerHTML = number;
}

function setNumbers() {
  var column = 0;
  var row = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    addCell(row, numbers[i]);
    if (column == 3) {
      column = 0;
      row = row + 1;
    } else {
      column++;
    }
  }
}
setNumbers()
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="0"></tr>
  <tr id="1"></tr>
  <tr id="2"></tr>
  <tr id="3"></tr>
</table>
```